# How to pass data from dialogflow(google assistant) to our android app installed in my mobile?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an android app which requires data from google assistant. While trying dialogflow, we can only able to call webhooks(http post call).

For eg, My app name is XYZ
configured phrase - "pass 2 to XYZ"

So if I say "pass 2 to XYZ", I need google assistant to open my app intent with the value 2 as param. So I can able to do my code flow with the value 2.

Answer (score 0):

Well I know you asked this 2 years and 9 months ago, so maybe you already found a solution. If not, then you can try using IFTTT. IFTTT allows you to program a catch phrase for google assistant, grab a variable and do something with it.

For example, I use it to pass commands back to my phone by sending notifications from IFTTT to my phone and then using Macrodroid on my phone to take action from the notifications.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).